# Multiple content types in SharePoint 2013 Library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, content-type, library, document-template

I was hoping to find an answer to my issue [in this article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/190841) but when adding multiple content types I run into a couple of issues. It works fine for .dotx templates, so I tried the same with an Excel and a PowerPoint template, but to no avail, I guess they don't like the "Document" parent type, or I must be missing some other point.

Firefox throws a "'New Document' requires a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible application and web browser." Why does it work with Word but not with Excel & Powerpoint?

Other browsers (Chrome, IE11, Edge) work to some extent. With PowerPoint custom content type:
- clicking New on a Library WebPart opens Powerpoint, attempts to authenticate to the domain and then says it can't connect.
- clicking New on the Library page itself creates a new file "POTX File.potx" based on the template in the library, but you have to open it manually.

With Excel custom content type:
- clicking New while Excel is already running on your PC creates a new book1.xlsx based on the template.
- clicking New when Excel is not running opens Excel but doesn't load the template.

Does somebody have some insight on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I need to collect the following information to further troubleshoot the issue:

Are you working in SharePoint online or SharePoint 2013?

If you are working in SharePoint 2013, have you configured OWA for SharePoint 2013?

Please offer a screenshot about where you are using the 'New Document' button.

Make sure the "Office Document Cache Handler" and "SharePoint OpenDocuments Class" managed ad-on are enabled:

[image]

Ensure you have valid entries inside DOCICON.XML

Folder: C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\XML

Here are some articles for your reference:

http://susheeldakoju.com/?p=1049

http://www.jeanpaulva.com/index.php/2012/08/15/error-new-document-requires-a-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-compatible-application-and-web-browser-to-add-a-document-to-this-document-library-click-the-upload-document-button/

Comment: SharePoint online and Office 2016. None of the mentioned add-ons are present. I have no Web Server Extensions folder on my PC, either. How do I respond and attach a screenshot? Thanks.

Comment: btw the first link refers to Office 2010 and the second throws a 503.